# Avoid index scan for the following query?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a following query in which I am trying to fetch articles with a certain keyword, ordered by ViewCount.

```
SELECT
    ART.Id
    , ART.Title
    , ART.MetaTitle
    , ART.InitialTitle     AS Slug
    , ART.Summary
    , ART.RootCategoryId
    , CAT.Name             AS RootCategory
    , ART.OldFacebookCommentsUrl
    , ICO.CssClass         AS Icon
    , ART.TopicName
    , ART.MainArticlePhoto AS MainImage
    , ART.FrontPagePhoto   AS HomePageImage
    , ART.PublishDate
    , ART.Sponsored
    , ART.PositionForCategory
    , ART.KeyInfo
    , AVS.ViewCountSum
FROM
    ArticleViewCountSum        AVS
    INNER JOIN Articles        ART
        ON ART.Id = AVS.ArticleId
    INNER JOIN ArticleKeywords AKW
        ON AKW.ArticleId = ART.Id
    INNER JOIN Categories      CAT
        ON CAT.Id = ART.RootCategoryId
    LEFT JOIN ArticleIcons     ICO
        ON ICO.Id = ART.IconId
WHERE
    AKW.KeywordId = 94090
    AND AKW.KeywordTypeId = 3
    AND ART.Active = 1
    AND ART.PublishDate <= GETDATE()
ORDER BY
    AVS.ViewCountSum DESC OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 10 ROWS ONLY;
```

Is it possible to avoid index scan for the following query and if so, how? Scan occurs on ArticleViewCountSum table.
Here is a screenshot of query plan.

[image: query plan]

This is ArticleViewCountSum table structure

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ArticleViewCountSum](
    [ArticleId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ViewCountSum] [int] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_ArticleViewCountSum] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ArticleId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [viewcountsum_articleid] ON [dbo].[ArticleViewCountSum]
(
    [ViewCountSum] ASC
)
INCLUDE (   [ArticleId]) WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

Index scan disappeares, if I remove where clause for ArticleKeywords written below, but then I do not get desired result. I am trying to fetch most read articles with specified tag/keyword.

```
AKW.KeywordId = 94090 
AND AKW.KeywordTypeId = 3
```

Comment: sql server optimizer use index scan if it predicts its returning more than 50% of data set , If that is not true then probably your statistics are out of date and you need to update them.

Comment: Who says an index scan is bad? An index scan is only bad *if a lot of rows are being scanned and discarded*. The best index in the world is one that is so specific that you don't need to do a lookup in it, you can just scan it.